# Test Class Failing for Custom Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I have a custom controller for which I've written a test class but getting an error when executing the Test -

Error Message   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
Stack Trace Class.FollowedCasesPageTest.testPage: line 39, column 1

Controller -

```
public class CaseListViewController {

public List<Case> getEntity() {
    List<EntitySubscription> results = [Select ParentID from EntitySubscription where SubscriberId=:UserInfo.getUserId() and ParentId IN (Select Id from Case) ];

    set<ID> IDSet = new set<Id>();
for(EntitySubscription et: results ) {
  IDSet.add(et.ParentID );
}
    list<Case> caseList=[select Id,Subject,Status,CaseNumber,CreatedDate,   Sub_Status__c,Type from case where ID IN:IdSet];
    return CaseList;
    
}
    public List<Case> getCases() {
    List<Case> results1 = [Select Id,Subject,Status,Type,CreatedDate,   Sub_Status__c,  CaseNumber from Case where createdby.id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
   return results1;
}
}
```

Test Class -

```
 @isTest 
private class FollowedCasesPageTest{
    
 @TestSetup
    static void setupData(){
        
        UserRole userrole = [Select Id, DeveloperName From UserRole  Limit 1];
        Profile sysadmin = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator']; 
        User adminUser =new User(UserRoleId =userrole.id,alias = 'standt', email='standarduser@testorg.com',emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', profileid = sysadmin.Id, timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='standarduserxxx@testorg.com');
        insert adminUser;
        
        System.runAs(adminUser){
            Account a = new Account(Name='Test Account Name');
            insert a;
            
            Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Last Name', AccountId = a.id,email='abc@def.com');
            insert c;
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    @isTest static void testPage()
    { 
        Test.startTest();
     User u=[Select id,name from User where email='standarduser@testorg.com'];
        System.runAs(u){
            
        
        
        Account a=[Select id from Account Limit 1];
        Contact c=[Select id from contact LIMIT 1];

         Case ca = new Case(Product_Categorisation__c='Mobile Application',Status='New',AccountId = a.id, ContactId = c.id, Subject='Test',origin='Phone',Type='Service Request',SuppliedEmail='sumeet.negi@condecosoftware.com');
            insert ca;
             Case case1=[Select Id from case LIMIT 1];
        EntitySubscription es=new EntitySubscription(ParentId=case1.ID);
            insert es;
        
        
       
        EntitySubscription ess=[Select id from EntitySubscription];
        
        
    }
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also define the User who is subscribed to the [EntitySubscription](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm)

```
EntitySubscription es = new EntitySubscription(
    ParentId = case1.Id,
    SubscriberId = u.Id);
insert es;
```

Of course, you can change the lookup reference to User in your test setup if you wish.

Comment: It worked like a charm, but the controller class is still showing test coverage as 0

Comment: I've passed the code coverage as well, thank you!